# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference at pizzaBaking/doRESTART()

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, null, object-reference

I have been working in this error for days, i keep searching and asking for help, (including reading from this site as well). It is basically involved a lot of external actionscript.

Every time i finish the interactive and i want to go back to previous frame, the error goes:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at pizzaBaking/doRESTART()
```

and this is the doRESTART function

```
public function doRESTART(e:MouseEvent):void{
        MovieClip(parent).gotoAndPlay(131);

        MovieClip(parent).MENUS.visible = false;
        MovieClip(parent).ABOUT.visible = false;
        MovieClip(parent).VOUCHER.visible = false;
        MovieClip(parent).UPDATES.visible = false;
```

Due to quite a few of file, i put it all in mediafire, in flash cs6 http://www.mediafire.com/download/10skpaizeyk2kul/pizzaHut.rar

thank you so much

Comment: If you could just post the contents of your `doRESTART()` method it would be a lot easier for people to help you.

Comment: Which line is it happening on? The error could be in 1 of 5 objects so we can't even begin to guess. One of your objects is not set, though, or `parent` is not a `MovieClip`. Additionally, it is a bad practice to call `parent` for anything more than logical checks. You should dispatch an event from `doRESTART` and listen for it in the parent object instead.

Comment: @JoshJanusch Overall my problem is only with this movieclips, i can't control them after i click the restart button. The movieclips just won't go invisible. Some suggest that i put the event listener in the wrong place.

If the parent is not a movieclip, should i just use parent.MENUS.visible = false; ?

Comment: Most likely your parent's references `MENUS`,`ABOUT` etc are invalidated when you press restart. Check if you assign something to them elsewhere.

Comment: @Vesper thanx for your comment above, as i recall i only have 1 main external action script for the main fla, and i don't have any other function for that MENUS, UPDATES, ABOUT, VOUCHER. The other external as3 are controlling their own movieclip. Any other advice?

Answer (score 0):

**1: Turn on Debugging**

Go to your publish settings and enable "Permit Debugging".  This will take your ambiguous error...

`null object reference at pizzaBaking/doRESTART()`

...to a much clearer...

`null object reference at pizzaBaking/doRESTART() script\pizzaBaking.as:35`

...which now denotes which line in your code to look for your issue.

[image]

---

**2: Use the Debug Console**

Use the debugging compile mode to bring up the Debug Console.  This will provide you with an immediate look at the line of code in question, as well as the Call Stack, and the state of all available Variables.  No programmer should be without one.

[image]

---

**3: parent == null**

When `doRESTART()` is being called, it no longer has a parent, ergo, when you call `MovieClip(parent)` it returns a null, and there is no `MENUS` property on `null`.  This is why it's reporting `null object reference`.

If I were you, I'd seriously reconsider how you're approaching this.  Remove all timeline code, and any use of frame animation.  This is likely the reason why your pizzaBaking class lost its parent relationship.  Also, there appear to be several instances in which you could consolidate repetitious code into a single function (`KeyboardPizza.as` being a prime example).  Consider passing a method an argument to modify its behavior, or use [`switch case`](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3switch/), or perhaps a [lookup table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table).

That said, press on.  It looks like you're making great progress on your project.

-Cheers

Comment: apparently doing frame animation is the best of what can i do currently, as i myself is designer, not a programmer. But I feel like asking you few question.
If i still want to remain my frame animation, but maybe do some tweak about the timeline code, how can i do that? (not to forget that my timeline code are just stop(); and play(); and that's it, which i found has less effect to any trouble)